# Custom deleter unique_ptr creates 'function not used' warnings in object code and error during linking

Tags: c++, c++20, smart-pointers

I am creating an object file for my larger program. In this program I use a `unique_ptr` type with a custom deleter defined.
So I'm compiling my file like so:

```
g++ -std=c++20 tmp.cpp -c -Wall
```

The code looks as follows:

```
#include <memory>

using specialptr = std::unique_ptr<int, decltype([](int *f) {
                     delete f;
                   })>;

specialptr fun(){ 
  return specialptr{new int};
}
```

This generates this warning:

```
 tmp.cpp:12:12: warning: ‘specialptr fun()’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   12 | specialptr fun(){ return specialptr{new int};}
      |
```

When I link this object file with a `main.cpp` that calls the function  I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
tmp.h:19:12: warning: ‘specialptr fun()’ used but never defined
   19 | specialptr fun();
      |            ^~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnuTTGC.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `fun()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is going on here? My code works when I change the return value from a `unique_ptr` to a normal pointer. But intuitively, I defined the type and function and made a declaration in a header file.

g++ is version: g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decltype` of a lambda is different for each translation unit.

You can instead do something like:

```
struct specialptr_deleter {
  void operator()(int *f) const {
    delete f;
  }
};

using specialptr = std::unique_ptr<int, specialptr_deleter>;

specialptr fun(){ 
  return specialptr{new int};
}
```

Comment: Ah yes okay. But that would mean giving the `Deleter` every time I use `specialptr` right? This leaves open the possibility of me forgetting to give it the right deleter. mmh

Comment: @TarickWelling Actually you can't forget to give deleter with such type. Compiler will not compile it in this case. But you can accidentaly or specially create pointers with different deleter implementations.

Comment: In that case you can use a struct. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use object type as deleter. In this case you don't need to set it every time you create `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(int *f) {
        std::cout << "Deleter called";
        delete f;
    }
};

using specialptr = std::unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter>;

specialptr fun(){ 
  return specialptr{new int};
}

int main()
{
    auto x = fun();
}
```